# Understanding the following equation

Tags: summation, random-variables, signal-processing, parameter-estimation, estimation

I have the following expression from Linear Least Square part of Steven M Kay book titled Fundamentals of statistical signal processing.

$\hat{\theta} = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]h[n]}{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h^2[n]}$ ---(1)

$\hat{\theta} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h[n](x[n]-\hat{\theta} h[n])$ ----(2)

It is written in book that when we substitute $\hat{\theta}$ from equation (1) into equation (2), summation in equation (2) reduces to zero.

However, I am not getting how this is happening. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key ideas are that you can "split" the summation and take out $\hat{\theta}$, since it does not depend on $n$.

If you take your second equation, you can rewrite it as:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h[n]x[n] - \hat{\theta}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h^2[n].
$$
Substituting with (1), you have:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h[n]x[n] - \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h[n]x[n]}{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h^2[n]}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h^2[n] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h[n]x[n] - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h[n]x[n] = 0.
$$

Comment: Thank u so much sir for ur response.....